# Segmentation Fault(coredump) during cat in an IF statement

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a file `ut.txt` which has a single value that is 385186 bytes long. I'm using the following to find whether the value is Numeric:

```
if [[ `cat ut.txt` = +([0-9]) ]]
then
echo "Numeric"
fi
```

This works perfect on smaller files. But with ut.txt(385186 bytes), it gives me the following error:

```
Segmentation Fault(coredump)
```

Can someone suggest a way to make this check while avoiding the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are kind of abusing the feature of the backquotes here.  They are not supposed to handle output which is that long.  A segfault is not what the ksh should react with, but I propose to use a streaming version instead:

```
if egrep -q '^[0-9]+$' ut.txt
then
  echo "Numeric"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you.. egrep sure would help me here (though i couldn't get -q to work). I considered taking the value in a valriable (variable 'a' in the commands below). Can you explain why the following don't work with very large values? To check for INTEGER: `[[ $a = +([0-9]) ]] && echo numeric` . To check for DECIMAL numbers: `[[ $a = +([0-9])\.+([0-9]) ]] && echo float`.  These give me the same "Segmentation Fault(coredump)" error when using very large values, but run perfect for small values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said, this feature is not meant for large data and if you use it with large data, it might overflow an internal buffer of ksh. If there is no check for this in the ksh, a segfault can be the result.  Regarding `-q`:  You can replace that by using a redirection to /dev/null: `if egrep '^[0-9]+$' >/dev/null`.

Comment: If you want to allow floats, just use `^[0-9.]+$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
grep -q '[a-zA-Z]' ut.txt || echo "Numeric"
```

Grep search for any of the defined sequences (`[a-zA-Z]`) and if not found (`||`) `echo`es what you want.

***Update*** as mentioned in the comment you might have another (e.g. non-ASCII, like accented) characters to classify as not numeric.

In that case you can use

```
grep -q '[^0-9]' ut.txt || echo "Numeric"
```

Which will search any other than digit character.

Comment: The problem here is that my file may even contain French characters. There may be other special symbols too, which I may not know about in advance. So, I want everything that has ONLY numbers to be considered "NUMERIC". If ANY other characters (other than decimals and numerals) appear in the file, the the value should NOT be considered numeric.